# Text mining using Java/R interface

Tags: java, r, file, text-mining, jri

I'm trying to do text mining using JRI for my file, this is my first time doing it. So this is my code:

```
    Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--vanilla"}, false, null);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    rengine.eval("library(\"tm\")");


    rengine.eval("filePath <- \"C:\\\\Users\\\\acer\\\\Desktop\\\\tp_ged\\\\doc1\\\\f1.txt\"");

    rengine.eval("text <- readLines(filePath)");

    rengine.eval("docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))");

     rengine.eval("docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))");
     rengine.eval("docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)");
     rengine.eval("docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords(\"english\"))");
     rengine.eval("docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)");
     rengine.eval("docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)");
     //String[] result = rengine.eval("docs<- Corpus(VectorSource(text))").asStringArray();
     System.out.println("---"+rengine.eval("inspect(docs)")));
```

but I'm getting `null` as a result, I think the tm library isn't loading or something, as I said before this is my first time doing this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with calling Java from R (usually for me the other way around), but does the `rengine.eval` call suppose to return the R output or is there a separate property on the object that stores the output? For example, will `System.out.println(rengine.eval("'Hello, Java'"))` print anything?

If it does return the R output, can you try something like `rengine.eval('loadedNamespaces()')` to check if tm is in fact loaded?

Comment: @MarcusA. i did  `System.out.println("---"+rengine.eval("loadedNamespaces()"));` and it has printed this: [STRING* ("compiler", "graphics", "utils", "grDevices", "stats", "datasets", "methods", "base")], so this means the tm library is loading correctly?!